# UICollectionView autosizing cells break UICollectionViewFlowLayout settings

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, ios8

I'm currently working on autosizing cells which are new in `iOS8`.

According to WWDC 2014 video 'What's New in Table and Collection Views', all that is required to autosize cells is to set an `estimatedSize` on the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` given to the `UICollectionView` on initialisation, and override the `sizeThatFits:` method in the `UICollectionViewCell`.

**Initialisation**:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

[flowLayout setEstimatedItemSize:CGSizeMake(146.0f, 156.0f)];

_collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:[_containerView bounds] collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

`sizeThatFits` method in my cell, where _userLabel is the label that is on the bottom and marks the actual height.

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
{
    CGSize actualSize = CGSizeMake([[self contentView] bounds].size.width, [_userLabel frame].origin.x + [_userLabel bounds].size.height);

    return actualSize;
}
```

It turns out that actual size has larger height than my estimated size, which should be okay and the cell actually gets resized properly in height.

Now with the iPhone6 and 6+, the width can also differ. I want the cells to properly span the width of the screen. I've therefore implemented three delegate methods on UICollectionViewFlowLayout; my first intuition is to calculate the width I want the cells to have according to the screen width, the section insets and the inter-item spacing.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIEdgeInsets sectionInsets = [self collectionView:collectionView layout:collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
    CGFloat interItemSpacing = [(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *) collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacing];

    CGFloat cellWidth = ([_collectionView bounds].size.width - sectionInsets.left - sectionInsets.right - interItemSpacing) / 2;

    CGSize collectionViewCellSize = CGSizeMake(cellWidth, 156.0f);

    return collectionViewCellSize;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 12.0f;
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{   
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f);
}
```

It works, however partly. The collectionView won't respect the top section inset, and when scrolling the collectionView, switching out another tab and then back again, cells seem to have disappeared.

Apparently I'm doing something wrong, but I can't seem to figure out where. Anyone got a clue?

Comment: I've had issues with this as well, insets are ignored :( I get the feeling it's just a bug. There's a demo project [here](https://github.com/algal/SelfSizingCellsDemo) that illustrates there's other bugs with it as well

Comment: setEstimatedItemSize Seems to cause me problems it is a performance enhancement "Providing an estimated cell size can improve the performance of the collection view when the cells adjust their size dynamically" Try use only setItemSize and see whether you still have issues.